# How does CombineLatest work compared to of

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, fork-join

I'm learning about `forkJoin`. I'm trying to wrap my head around how it works compared to creating an observable with `of`. Please tell me if I have this right:

When I use `of`, it creates an observable that will emit the value you pass to it right away. So if I have this:

```
const obs = of('hello');

obs.subscribe(console.log);
```

...it will log 'hello' as soon as the line where I subscribe to `obs` executes. Is this correct?

Now if I have this:

```
const obs1 = httpClient.get(url1);

const obs2 = httpClient.get(url2);

const fjObs = forkJoin({obs1, obs2});

fjObs.subscribe(({obs1, obs2}) => console.log(`obs1=${obs1}, obs2=${obs2}`));
```

...it WON'T log `obs1` and `obs2` as soon as the line where I subscribe to fjObs executes. It will log them only when both obs1 and obs2 have completed, which could be a while after I subscribe to fjObs. Is this correct?

And until that happens, fjObs is just an observable that has not yet emitted any values. Is that correct?

Please let me know if my understanding is correct. Thank you.

Comment: The title says `combineLatest` vs `of` but the question asks about `forkJoin` vs `of`. Please note `combineLatest` and `forkJoin` are not the same.

Comment: ForkJoin emits when all Observables have completed (tip: never give an empty array of observables to ForkJoin or it will never emit & complete).
CombineLatest starts emiting when all Obs. have emitted at least one value(!) and it emits all latest values from each Obs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are basically correct. <strike>Please note that `forkJoin` accepts an array of observables, so your code should be: `const fjObs = forkJoin([obs1, obs2]);`</strike> *as pointed out in the comment, this assumption was wrong*

also you could test this:
`forkJoin([of('one'), of('two')]).subscribe(console.log);`
in this case the console.log will be executed immediatly since both `of` emits immediatly.

you could also do: `forkJoin([of('one'), httpClient.get(url1)]).subscribe(console.log);` in this case it will log after the HTTP request is completed.

**You should not compare** `of` with `forkJoin` since those are very different concepts.
`of` creates an observable and `forkJoin` combines an array of observables and emits (the last value of each observable) when all <strike>have emitted a value</strike> completed

Comment: _"Please note that `forkJoin` accepts an array of observables, so your code should be:"_ -this isn't true. You could also pass a dictionary of observable to `forkJoin` like OP is doing. In that case the emission would be an object of signature `{ obs1: <emission from obs1>, obs2: <emission from obs2> }`. Interestingly until RxJS v7 you could also pass arguments as [JS rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`forkJoin(obs1, obs2)`) but it's deprecated in v7 and will be gone in v8.

Comment: _"`forkJoin` combines an array of observables and emits when all have emitted a value"_ - this statement is inaccurate. `forkJoin` emits notifications from all it's source observables when all of them *complete* as opposed to `combineLatest` and `zip` which emit values when all their source observables have *emitted* at least once.

Comment: true, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer zerotwelve. I have tried `forkJoin([of('one'), of('two')]).subscribe(console.log)` and `forkJoin([of('one'), httpClient.get(url1)]).subscribe(console.log)` and they behave just as you described.